# Signal/Slot OpenCV Mat over different threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I aggregate images from a hardware (PointGrey) camera and put them into opencv matrices in a dedicated (camera) thread. I want to display these images in a QWidget which is running in another (gui) thread.

If the image aggregation and the gui are running in the same thread, everything is fine memory-wise, but as soon as the camera is running in another thread, I get a memory leak, because the opencv matrices are not deleted properly.

The whole thing looks as follows:

```
 Thread A                         Thread B
+---------+                      +---------+
| Camera  |                      | QWidget |
+---------+                      +---------+
     |                                |
     | emit camFrame(frame);--------->|
     |                                |-> setImage(cv::Mat frame);
     |                                |
```

I connect the camFrame signal with the setImage slot inside a QMainWindow instance:

```
mCameraThread = new QThread;
mCamera->moveToThread(mCameraThread);

/* connect camera with attached thread */
connect(mCameraThread, SIGNAL(started()), mCamera, SLOT(start()));
connect(mCamera, SIGNAL(stopped()), mCameraThread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(mCamera, SIGNAL(stopped()), mCamera, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(mCameraThread, SIGNAL(finished()), mCameraThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

/* connect camera with camerawidget thread */
connect(mCamera, SIGNAL(camFrame(cv::Mat)), mCameraPreviewWidget, SLOT(setImage(cv::Mat)));

/* start camera in separate thread with high priority */
mCameraThread->start();
mCameraThread->setPriority(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
```

I am not allocating new memory when sending the opencv matrix to the other thread, so I have no idea, why the memory leak is happening. I am doing:

```
Image rawImage;
mError = mCamera.RetrieveBuffer(&rawImage);

cv::Mat tmpFrame(rawImage.GetRows(), rawImage.GetCols(), CV_8UC1);
tmpFrame.data = rawImage.GetData();
cv::Mat actualFrame = tmpFrame.clone();
tmpFrame.release();
emit camFrame(actualFrame)
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction of what is possibly going wrong here? Thanks in advance

**FIXED**

Thanks, everybody. The example code above is fine actually. My mistake was that I accidentally started the camera twice codewise. While playing with the second thread, I forgot to remove the line

```
mCamera->start()
```

from my code. Sorry for your time because of this stupid mistake.

Comment: if your Mat is coming from a webcam, then it is pointing to static memory inside the capture, and you will have to clone() it.

Comment: I am now cloning the mat and release the first one right after (edited question), but the memory leak is still happening.

Comment: Hi ! Passing object arguments through signal between threads is not trivial. I advice you to pass a reference, a smart pointer or a pointer. (See this link for very good information about this: http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/ )

Comment: it won't help, but you're not allowed to release() the Mat from the webcam. (see [note here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read))

Comment: This is a comment for people who come across this problem afterwards. I found out that using cv::Mat& as a type will not work in current QT's signals-slot mechanism. Always use cv::Mat !

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV won't automatically release the resources when the data is assigned by a pointer("frame.data = rawImage.GetData();"). You might want to make a copy or manually release the Mat.

Comment: I made a copy of the data (edited question above) and released the mat right after, but the memory leak is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment yet, thus an answer:

Did you register the type via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`?
Because maybe Qt is not actually sending `cv::Mat` but instead using one of the many conversion operators of `cv::Mat`.

Qt 5.3.1 documentation for `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` (emphasis and note are mine):

> Adding a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() makes the type known to all template based functions, including QVariant. Note that if you intend to use the type in queued signal and slot connections [1] or in QObject's property system, you **also** have to call qRegisterMetaType() since the names are resolved at runtime.

[1] Which happens on multi threading by default.

Comment: Yes, I did qRegisterMetaType<cv::Mat>("cv::Mat"); at the beginning of the constructor of my qmainwindow

Comment: At least I can comment my own answers. ;) According to the documentation cv::Mat should work on multiple threads. Have you the most recent version of it?

Comment: Try with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, there is a warning in regard to qRegisterMetaType usage in the Qt docs.

Comment: I am using Qt 4.8 here. I tried declaring opencv mat with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(cv::Mat) before my main function without any luck. Memory is still leaking :-(